# Lazy loading angular components with ngx-bootstrap TabsModule

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using the TabsModule from gx-bootstrap in my angular app. Each tab has an angular component contained within it. When the page loads and, by default, opens the first tab all the other tabs are also loaded. Is there a way to lazy load the tabs which are displayed/selected yet, or at least refresh them once the tab has been selected for view?

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1):

in ngx-bootstrap there is 'Dynamic Tabs' which I think will help you.

you can read about the [documentation](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tabs#tabs-dynamic).

Comment: Thank you. How would you recommend I load the different components with this?